# Enlarge NetLogo (menus, fonts) to fit high screen resolution

Tags: netlogo

for NetLogo 5.3.1 on linux/Gnome: my screen has a 2550 * 1440 resolution and makes NetLogo almost unreadable. I know that during a running session, I can increase the font size in the editor. But where can I configure NetLogo to always start with a larger font size?
The menu icons and fonts are tiny. Any way to configure NetLogo to make them larger?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

The [JEP 263: HiDPI Graphics on Windows and Linux](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/263) defines the appropiate behaviour of the OpenJDK for HiDPI, it's implemented in OpenJdk 9 so:

- Install OpenJdk 9
- Open NetLogo.cfg (mine is at /opt/netlogo/app/NetLogo.cfg)

  - To find it use in shell:

    `whereis NetLogo
    ls -l /usr/bin/NetLogo
    ls -l /opt/netlogo/app`
- Add at the **[JVMOptions]** section
  `-Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel
  -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on 
  -Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true`

To use the GTK L&F that is prepared to HiDPI, then you can use the **GNOME Tweak Tool** to balance the font size.

Comment: This settings do not change anything on my Windows PC, but they slow the app down quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

With OpenJDK >= 9, the UI can be scaled via an environment variable:

`bash -c 'export GDK_SCALE=2 && java -jar /PATH_OF_NETLOGO/app/netlogo-6.2.0.jar' &`